# Add a linkbutton (hyperlink) to Text attribute of a Control in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on ASP.net page and is there a way I could add a linkbutton to Text attriubte of another control, say a checkbox. So something like this,

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAccept" ForeColor="Red" Text="Check this box if you  can see <linkbutton onclick-"dosomething()> this popup</linkbutton></asp:CheckBox>
```

Here, user will see the text in checkbox but, "this popup" will be a linkbutton to open a popup.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a control inside the attribute of another control. What I would do is take the text out of the control and have it appear as separate markup after the control. Then you can do whatever you want.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAccept" ForeColor="Red" />
<span>Check this box if you  can see <asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="dosomething()" Text="this popup" />.</span>
```

Comment: I would also recommend that you learn about user-controls, in user controls you can have a customized control that includes the checkbox and the hyperlink, then make the hyperlink a public property and you can access the hyperlink properties like the navigationUrl, target, etc... That would make your maintainability much easier, would let you create your controls from code behind quick and easy and you would only have to worry about 1 control per instance instead of 2 (checkbox and hyperlink)